# Adding a secondary image to a nth child when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background image when the item is clicked. I want a cover photo - when clicked and opened the image changes to a background photo.

```
.el:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.cont.s--el-active .el:nth-child(1):not(.s--active) {
  transform: scale(0.5) translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.95s, opacity 0.95s;
}

.el:nth-child(1) .el__inner {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.el:nth-child(1) .el__bg {
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.el:nth-child(1) .el__bg:before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
   background-image: 
    url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2084/8209/files/IMG_8289.JPG? 
    13764159910008904703");
}
```

I want to add a second image as this currently displays only one image as when closed and opened.

[Here is what I'm trying to replicate from CodePen](https://codepen.io/suez/pen/AXQaEg?editors=1111)

I should mention I have converted the SCSS to CSS

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replicate, so far I see two behaviors, one on hover the other on click. There is also JavaScript involved...where's yours?

Comment: I can't fit it in a comment but it's the same as the JS in the codepen link.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the active class set there:

```
.el:nth-child(1).s--active .el__bg:before {
    background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/onepgscr-3.jpg")!important;
}
```

Or use :after so you are able to do some transitions instead of replacing first image directly.

Comment: I tried using: .el:nth-child(1).s--active .el__bg:after {
    background-image: url(" URL HERE ") 

and had no luck as it would quickly switch back and forth and seemed clunky. Did I miss something?

Comment: Try again ;) You are missing . on before the `el`